# Running simple script using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I am trying to run a very simple script as a service along with other service using docker-compose. I have created an image using Dockerfile with following details :

```
FROM bash 
CMD bash test_script.sh
```

I have redis and test_script images installed. My docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '2'
services:

    redis:
       image: redis

    test-script:
       image: test-script
```

My test_script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "***************** Sleeping *****************"
sleep 10
echo "***************** Woke Up ******************"
```

When I run "docker-compose up", Redis starts properly but I get "bash: test_script.sh: No such file or directory". Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is telling you the truth.  You need to `COPY` your `test_script.sh` into the container.  Something like:

```
FROM bash 
COPY test_script.sh /test_script.sh
CMD bash test_script.sh
```

This assumes that there is a file named `test_script.sh` in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`.